# Best backend and frontend to create a website

Tags: website, iis, frontend

I'm supposed to create a website for our college. Students can login and enter their details. Which is the best backend and frontend? And it should run on IIS. Please give me some suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET is pretty standard for windows servers. ASP.NET MVC is a decent framework worth looking in to.